# Сравнение векторов из пользовательских типов

Tags: c++, stl

Стоит задача реализации калькулятора многочленов. Я реализовываю класс многочлена следующим образом:

1) Существует класс переменной, который содержит в себе информацию о букве, которая ее представляет, и степени. Для переменной перегружены операторы == и != и оператор вывода.

Код:

variable.h

```
class Variable
{
public:
    char letter;
    long int degree;

    Variable() = default;
    Variable(char l, long int d)
        : letter(l), degree(d) {}

    bool operator == (Variable & other);
    bool operator != (Variable & other);

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & stream, const Variable & var);

};
```

variable.cpp

```
bool Variable::operator == (Variable & other)
{
    return this->degree == other.degree && this->letter == other.letter;
}

bool Variable::operator != (Variable & other) 
{ 
    return !((*this) == other); 
}
```

2) Существует класс одночлена, который представляет собой коэффициент и вектор из переменных. Для него также перегружены операторы сравнения и оператор вывода.

Entry.h

```
class PolynomEntry
{
public:
    long int coeff;
    std::vector<Variable> var;

    PolynomEntry() = default;
    PolynomEntry(long c, Variable v) : coeff(c)
    {
        var.push_back(v);
    }
PolynomEntry(long c, std::vector<Variable> v) : coeff(c), var(v)
{}

bool operator == (PolynomEntry & other) { return this->var == other.var; }
bool operator != (PolynomEntry & other) { return this->var != other.var; }

friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & stream, const PolynomEntry & entry);

};
```

Но как только я пытаюсь использовать операторы сравнения через вектора, то получаю ошибки:

```
Error   C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'
```

Которые отсылают меня в глубины файла xutility. Гугление привело к выводу, что я как-то неправильно реализовал сравнение своих пользовательских типов и оператор сравнения вектора не может это переварить, но как реализовать правильно то, что нужно мне не имею никакого понятия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> bool operator == (Variable & other);
> ```

```
bool operator == (const Variable &other) const;
```

С остальными аналогично.

И ещё я бы рекомендовал реализовать `operator <`.